# Using C++ dll (Built in VS 2005) in C# (.Net 4.5)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2005

I am using a third party SDK with C++ dlls,

C# (.Net 2.0) sample is given with SDK which is built in Visual Studio 2005 and runs perfectly,
But **when I upgrade** the C# project **to .Net 4.5** (VS 2015), the C++ **dlls stops working,**

Most probably C++ dll is legacy dll and C# runtime is unable to consume it,

Already tested scenarios

1. Tested with .net 2.0
2. x86 and x64 architecture
3. Vs2015, vs2013, vs 2008, vs2005(this works perfectly)

My question is somehow resembles to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/24/stuck-on-an-older-toolset-version-move-to-visual-studio-2015-without-upgrading-your-toolset/) but the blog is related to c++

**Edit**

When using vs2005, it loads old vc++ runtime i.e. v80 which is compatible with third party dlls,

Can we load old vc++ runtime v80 with latest visual studio?

Comment: Check that you are not mixing x86 with x64.  Try building your .NET app as **x86** instead of **Any CPU**

Comment: I have already did this workaround but this didn't solve this issue.

Comment: I have already done Testing with 2.0 .net framework, x86 and x64 architecture, vs 2008, 2013, 2015
.Actual Issue is with third party c++ dll which is built through old c++ runtime and new visual studio is not loading it well

Comment: Well _"stops working"_ and _"not loading it well"_ isn't helpful.  It's premature to blame the third party c++ dll until we know more. [ask]

Comment: Actually c++ dll is communicating with a PCI telephony card, not loading implies that while loading the drivers of hardware, exception has been thrown that drivers could not be loaded

Comment: The plot thickens.    Did you change your OS?

Comment: Nope I tested only on windows 7 32bit